# Differences between POSIX O_SEARCH, and Linux O_PATH applied to a directory?

Tags: linux, language-lawyer, posix, portability

POSIX.1-2008 specifies an open(2) flag `O_SEARCH` which is specified in one sentence

> Open directory for search only.

plus more verbiage scattered over the definition of all the file-access system calls.

The Linux kernel does not provide this flag; instead it has `O_PATH`, which the manpage describes thus:

> Obtain a file descriptor that can be used for two  purposes: to indicate a location in the filesystem tree and to perform operations that act purely at the file descriptor level. [488 more words follow]

It appears to me, based on skimming the scattered POSIX verbiage, that O_PATH applied to a directory is more or less equivalent to O_SEARCH.  (O_PATH can also be applied to other types of file but that's not what interests me right now.)  However, "more or less" could be hiding any number of nasty gotchas.

So: I'm looking for a detailed and comprehensive list of differences between the actually-implemented semantics of O_PATH applied to a directory, and the specified semantics of O_SEARCH.  To put it another way, what are *all* the cases where

```
#define O_SEARCH   (O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY)
```

fails to provide the expected semantics of O_SEARCH?

Comment: My reading of `man 2 open` says that `O_PATH` is completely different from `O_SEARCH`. Have you tried to use it? In a normal Unix-y system, `O_SEARCH` should be the same as `O_EXEC` because traditionally these things are governed by the same bit in the permissions word.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I'm not aware of any OS that actually provides O_SEARCH, so it's very hard to test it!  But if you look over the POSIX spec, it should become clear that the POSIX committee _intended_ O_SEARCH to be used for the same things that people use O_PATH (on a directory) for on Linux (e.g. the dirfd argument to openat).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I take that back; FreeBSD (13.x, didn't check older versions) has O_SEARCH.  That makes the question substantially less academic: if you're trying to port Linux-specific code that uses O_PATH to *BSD, it seems like the best available substitute is O_SEARCH, and therefore you need to be clear on the differences.